# save output of for loop in csv python

Tags: python, loops, csv, output

I would like to write and save a file in a CSV format with the output of a for loop that has iterated through multiple columns doing a substraction, I tried to avoid getting only the last result out of the forward loop by creating a list and appending each output of the forward loop but I cannot save it in a file.  How could I save the output of a for loop including the result of all the iterations?

```
my_list = []
for column in df_intensity:
    bc_subs=column-col_background
    my_list.append(bc_subs)
my_list.to_csv(bc_subs_dataset)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv

This is an example of the output from the loop which I would like to save in which earch array is a column and the values inside are a raw

[array([1.        , 0.98667283, 0.93550512, 0.9101134 , 0.86350843,
       0.81362023, 0.79597313, 0.78630291, 0.76510444, 0.75112696,
       0.7234127 , 0.67824771, 0.69490244, 0.6833024 , 0.66117702,
       0.65868979, 0.64057607, 0.63110644, 0.63615269, 0.62496015,
       0.60352309, 0.57550056, 0.57964102, 0.57913217, 0.56365982,
       0.56177011, 0.55913509, 0.54846617, 0.5328418 , 0.52893359,
       0.52281686, 0.51125694, 0.50688211, 0.50002639, 0.49703454,
       0.48903232, 0.48262422, 0.47919319, 0.47335517, 0.4617129 ,
       0.45936713, 0.45944314, 0.45120023, 0.44460632, 0.44633978,
       0.43909345, 0.4300482 , 0.42903051, 0.42858922, 0.41968333,
       0.41303453, 0.41408601, 0.41192182, 0.40449602, 0.39662471,
       0.39829905, 0.38950084, 0.38282248, 0.38111647, 0.38575944,
       0.38395841, 0.37587597, 0.37590553, 0.37568172, 0.36958821,
       0.36520072, 0.36625431, 0.366419  , 0.36181403, 0.35568252,
       0.35645952, 0.35439245, 0.34876346, 0.34785344, 0.34985928,
       0.34836651, 0.34026507, 0.34158047, 0.34035586, 0.33751602,
       0.33338823]), array([1.        , 0.93300358, 0.82632603, 0.75321894, 0.68761633,
       0.62084654, 0.54310758, 0.5185884 , 0.50324798, 0.47731232,
       0.45328608, 0.42844111, 0.40683137, 0.37678228, 0.34402488,
       0.33740995, 0.32821703, 0.32341518, 0.31695605, 0.31059041,
       0.30151931, 0.29151617, 0.28407967, 0.27781886, 0.26899988,
       0.26574199, 0.25831966, 0.25317503, 0.2507132 , 0.2455034 ,
       0.23800742, 0.23385715, 0.22952557, 0.22541212, 0.2245679 ,
       0.22132701, 0.22111737, 0.21762435, 0.21395851, 0.21310862,
       0.20941729, 0.20923881, 0.20954761, 0.20692713, 0.20309698,
       0.20244257, 0.20250206, 0.19672001, 0.19553867, 0.19554434,
       0.1938219 , 0.19416752, 0.1948191 , 0.19383607, 0.19041387,
       0.18685285, 0.18603696, 0.18827499, 0.18781322, 0.18971696,
       0.18736844, 0.18885008, 0.1817932 , 0.18030873, 0.18086399,
       0.18121811, 0.17875061, 0.18166005, 0.17539073, 0.17018094,
       0.17242464, 0.17156625, 0.1754304 , 0.17486664, 0.17447852,
       0.17407341, 0.17018661])

Many thanks!!

Comment: you can not save a `list` to `csv` in this way. Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: If you do not use pandas, the `csv` module from the standard library should be enough here.

Comment: Im using Numpy im working with arrays

Comment: so if I delete the list step....how could I accumulate the output of the loop and save it in a csv file?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] explaining how you process the numpy arrays and what is the csv that you would like to build.